# Can we have the storage account name as part of the URL in Azure, to make the request untraceable?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I am building an anti-censorship app, and for it work my static files need to be hidden from the plain view. The problem is the way the Azure bucket account handles the public URL, so to access a file you will have to go to:

> https://STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/public/logo.png

Since the storage account name is part of the subdomain name, the HTTPS request to `STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net`, can be singled out and blocked.

Is there a way for the URL to be something like:

> https://blob.core.windows.net/STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME/public/logo.png

That way the URL resolved will be `blob.core.windows.net` and the rest will be encrypted, making it impossible to block without closing access to every other Azure request.

I know S3 works that way, but since we are a non-profit, Microsoft gracefully offered us free server space, so we would like to use Azure.

Thanks for your help. I am new to Azure.

Comment: "*since we are a non-profit, Microsoft gracefully offered us free server space*" Since you seem to already have an existing relationship with Microsoft, it may be prudent to ask them directly if they have other clients with whom this requirement is critical, and how they managed to solve for it.

Comment: S3 generally does not work that way either, the path-style access is deprecated (but still works), the domain-style access is the recommended one.

Comment: Hi @SalviPascual, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 1):

•   I would suggest you **configure a custom domain for your Azure tenant and map that custom domain to the Azure blob storage endpoint or instead configure a static website in your Azure storage account and map a custom domain to it**. `Once you map the custom domain to your blob service endpoint or to any container in your storage account, then the format of the URL is changed` to as shown below: -

```
https://<subdomain.customdomain>/<mycontainer>/<myblob>
```

In the above URL, the `name of the storage account is not shown in any way and instead the name of your organization as the custom domain is shown, thus effectively encrypting the name of the storage account, and implying that your organization has authority over the contents of the blob storage and the storage account itself`.

•   To **configure a custom domain and map it to the Azure blob storage account**, kindly refer to the below documentation that explains in detail the whole process to be followed for this purpose.

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal***

Also, do refer to the below community thread for details on **configuring the DNS zone and the respective records in it for the Azure storage account and its inherent content**: -

***[Configure a custom domain name for an azure blob storage endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015374/configure-a-custom-domain-name-for-an-azure-blob-storage-endpoint)***